# HashMap<Integer, double[]> equivalent in trove?

Tags: java, memory-management, hashmap, trove4j

I have just learned about trove library and how it's more memory efficient than JDK's Maps. I was previously using a hash map to store `totalSize = 2^N` **double array** entries, as follows:

> final Map myTable = new HashMap(totalSize);

I was wondering if there is an equivalent class in Trove? or if there is a way to use **Class TIntDoubleHashMap** that makes the same collection as *myTable* HashMap?

I would appreciate any help/suggestion.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried `THashMap<Integer, double[]>`?

Comment: That works but I'm not sure if it is any different from jdk hashmap ? since it has to use Integer rather than int. I'm switching to trove to be able to work with primitive types.

Comment: OK, then the correct answer is what @LouisWasserman gave you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `double[]` is, in fact, an object, so you should probably just use `TIntObjectHashMap<double[]>`.